# HTTP to HTTPS Redirection Not Working; Makes the Website to Go Into an Infinite Loop

Tags: apache, http, https

We are trying via a .htaccess file to redirect all pages from HTTP to HTTPS. But, when we add the code it makes the website (built in WordPress and using Apache) to go into infinite loop and hence, the website goes down.

Need the website to load without "www."

We were successfully able to do that only for the homepage of the website.

The developer has tried adding these two code versions to .htaccess file but to no success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.healthyceleb.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://healthyceleb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^healthyceleb.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.healthyceleb.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.healthyceleb.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any kind of code you would suggest?

The .htaccess file content below -

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

deny from 72.21.217.0/24

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.healthyceleb.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://healthyceleb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Deny From 208.72.130.74
#MITIGATE XMLRPC ATTACKS - ADDED BY HOSTGATOR#
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 416 "Invalid Request"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^POST /xmlrpc.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [R=416,L]

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
# BEGIN Configurable Hotlink Protection
# END Configurable Hotlink Protection

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# force deflate for mangled headers
# developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
 # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare  COMPRESS
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/html|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/css|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/plain|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/xml|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/x-component|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/javascript|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/json|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/xml|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/xhtml+xml|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/rss+xml|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/atom+xml|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/vnd.ms-fontobject|"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'image/svg+xml'"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'image/x-icon'"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
        FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'font/opentype'"
        FilterChain    COMPRESS
        FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
  # Legacy versions of Apache
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
 </IfModule>
 </IfModule>

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .js2
AddType text/javascript .js3
AddType text/x-js .js4
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/xsd .xsd
AddType text/xsl .xsl
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType image/bmp .bmp
AddType application/java .class
AddType video/divx .divx
AddType application/msword .doc .docx
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType image/webp .webp
AddType application/json .json
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._otf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType image/png .png
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._ttf
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType image/webp A31536000
ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
   </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon image/webp application/json application/vnd.ms-access application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint image/svg+xml application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
   <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
     </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5.4"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5.4"
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|WEBP|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
   FileETag MTime Size
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5.4"
  </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|class|doc|docx|eot|exe|ico|webp|json|mdb|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|svg|svgz|swf|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|BMP|CLASS|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|ICO|WEBP|JSON|MDB|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW)$">
 FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header unset Last-Modified
 </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
 # END W3TC Browser Cache
 # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -F
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
  # END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Can you add the .htaccess or at least the rules?

Comment: When you want to redirect from http to https you have to use openSSL certificates in your code.Are you using ????

Comment: @Syed Ayesha Bebe - Yes, using the COMODO SSL certificate

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files or you can only use .htaccess

Comment: No, we have access to only .htaccess file.

Comment: Do you also need to enforce using bare domain name (without www.)?

Comment: Yes, need the website to load without www.

Answer (score 0):

First revert .htacces back to previous state, then add this to the top:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://healthyceleb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^healthyceleb\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://healthyceleb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Finally, replace any `http` in your current rules with `https`.
Once you are certain that it works OK, change `R=302` to `R=301`

Comment: Thanks Dusan Bajic. Your answer was really helpful.
Problem Solved!!